# Python classifiers

Tags: python, pandas, plot, scikit-learn, classification

I'm starting a career with python. I can't deal with this problem

MY CODE:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dFrame=pd.read_csv('...', header='infer', sep=" ")
#importing the necessary packages
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
feature_cols=["Attr1", "Attr2", "Attr3", "Attr4"]
X=dFrame[feature_cols]
y=dFrame['Decision']
y=dFrame.Decision
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y)
NB = GaussianNB()
NB.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_predict = NB.predict(X_test)
print("Accuracy NB: {:.2f}".format(NB.score(X_test, y_test)))

print("Means:", NB. theta_ )
print("Standard deviations:" , NB.sigma_ )
print(X_train)
print(y_train)
def plot_ellipse ( ax , mu , sigma , color = "k" , label = None ):

    import matplotlib.patches
# Compute eigenvalues and associated eigenvectors
    vals , vecs =np.linalg.eigh(sigma)

    # Compute "tilt" of ellipse using first eigenvector
    x , y = vecs[:, 0]
    theta = np.degrees (np.arctan2 ( y , x ))

 # Eigenvalues give length of ellipse along each eigenvector
    w,h = 2 * np.sqrt ( vals )
    ax . tick_params ( axis = 'both' , which = 'major' , labelsize = 20 )
    ellipse = matplotlib.patches.Ellipse ( mu, w, h, theta, color = color, label = label )  # color="k")
    ellipse . set_clip_box ( ax . bbox )
    ellipse . set_alpha ( 0.2 )
    ax . add_artist ( ellipse )
    return ellipse
```

error text:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PhytonProjekty/untitled/proba.py", line 47, in <module>
    plot_ellipse (plt.gca (),NB.theta_[0], np.identity(2)*NB.sigma_[0],color = "red" )
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,2) (4,)
```

data table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xn5Kl.png)
Thank you for any help

Comment: Your code snippet is incomplete. Please edit. Just looking in my jawbreaker, I would guess that the error occurs because of your "ax" variable that you pass to the function  `plot_ellipse`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in `np.identity(2)*NB.sigma_[0]`.

You have four features so, `NB.sigma_[0]` is of shape `(4,)`. You want to multiply it with identity matrix of shape `(2, 2)` by using `np.identity(2)`. So the matrix multiplication is not working and hence the error.

Do you want to do something like

```
np.identity(4)*NB.sigma_[0]
```

?

Comment: I did it from the guide: https://saskeli.github.io/data-analysis-with-python-summer-2019/bayes.html
current error:
Name: Decision, Length: 1029, dtype: int64
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PhytonProjekty/untitled/proba.py", line 47, in <module>
    plot_ellipse (plt.gca (),NB.theta_[0], np.identity(4)*NB.sigma_[0],color = "red" )
  File "D:/PhytonProjekty/untitled/proba.py", line 32, in plot_ellipse
    x , y = vecs[:, 0]
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: @CaponeAll That particular code only works with 2 features. Not more